# SELECT * FROM help

Tags: php, mysql

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | dataA | dataB |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |    75 |   100 |
|  2 |   256 |    75 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Hey, just wondering how I could select ONLY the data in dataA with id=1 ?? The table is called stats ie: $query = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE      and this is where I am stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select dataA from stats where id=1;
```

Comment: Ah! of coarse. I must have gotten myself confused trying to start with stats. That you so much!

Comment: Quick question though. How would I echo that result to the page?

Comment: Have a look at the example code in the manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php , it explains how to retrieve data from the MySQL database and display it to screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
select dataA from stats 
             where id=1;
```

Also note that you subject line says to select everything but the question content says to select tuples of `dataA` where `id=1` only.

Comment: matthewh beat ya to it :p but thank you as well for the quick response!