# SELECT * FROM help - with 2 variable options

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I found a question in this post here:

[SELECT * FROM help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050745/select-from-help)

I have a question that slightly elaborates on this:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | dataA | dataB |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |    75 |   100 |
|  2 |   256 |    75 |
|  3 |    75 |   150 |
|  4 |   256 |   100 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

So the question that was posted was: how to select ONLY the data in dataA with id=1

But my question is: How to select data (seeing id1) that has data A = 75 and data B = 150?

So not getting the row by id, but something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dataA = '75' & WHERE dataB = '150';"
```

I hope I am on the right track here:-)

--Jwk82

Comment: `&` not exists in mysql, use `AND` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dataA = '75' AND dataB = '150';"

unless im reading this request incorrectly this is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

close, try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dataA = 75 AND dataB = 150
```

Comment: Yeah it was missing the quotation marks, but I just added the AND and it worked - thanks a lot:-)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you got it right, except you only need to specify the WHERE clause once.

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dataA = '75' AND dataB = '150';"
```

And this is assuming `dataA` and `dataB` are of a string type. If they are numerical, you will want to remove the single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You're very close. Use the word `AND` (and only use `WHERE` once), i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dataA = '75' AND dataB = '150'
```

If `dataA` and `dataB` are integers and not strings, you should remove the single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dataA = 75 AND dataB = 150
```

The `AND` will require that both are true. If you want to select a row where either is true, you use `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dataA = 75 OR dataB = 150
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dataA = '75' AND dataB = '150';"
```

Additionally, you should probably remove the quotes around the numbers (since they're numbers); however, it should work either way.

Answer (score 1):

try: SELECT * FROM table WHERE dataA='75' AND dataB='150';

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand something but:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dataA = 75 AND dataB = 150;
```

Comment: @KaiQing: You're certainly right, I stand (stood :P) corrected.

Comment: @KaiQing: I got mislead by his id=1 in the question, thought further than id1 doesn't have dataB = 150, hence he wants OR, from which I did the query, without reading through other table entries. Stupid of me.